# Kibana Aggregation Visualisation of a Field (userid) having Multiple Values of Field (bank_name)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So I have an index with two fields `userid` and bank_name. Every-time a user get a new bank account, a value is inserted with the `userid` and the bank's name in which the user opened the account. I have to use `kibana` and `elasticsearch` to create a visualization (let say a pie chart) that displays all the count of users having more than 2 (or 4 this can change) bank accounts in the same bank name.

I have tried creating sub-buckets but that gives two things the first one displaying the total count of bank names partitioned according to their value and the second one showing how many times each user has had a account in that bank. I have searched around and think I have to use the sub_doc_count somewhere in the aggs, but cannot figure out where or how to do so.

So for example for following data:

```
[{
  "_id": 10001,
  "userid": 0,
  "bank_name": "xyz bank",
  "date": "2019-01-23"
},
 {
   "_id": 10002,
   "userid": 0,
   "bank_name": "abc bank",
   "date": "2019-01-29"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10003,
   "userid": 1,
   "bank_name": "xyz bank",
   "date": "2019-01-31"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10004,
   "userid": 2,
   "bank_name": "def bank",
   "date": "2019-02-02"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10005,
   "userid": 2,
   "bank_name": "abc bank",
   "date": "2019-02-03"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10006,
   "userid": 1,
   "bank_name": "xyz bank",
   "date": "2019-02-10"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10007,
   "userid": 1,
   "bank_name": "abc bank",
   "date": "2019-02-14"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10008,
   "userid": 0,
   "bank_name": "abc bank",
   "date": "2019-02-20"
 },
 {
   "_id": 10009,
   "userid": 0,
   "bank_name": "xyz bank",
   "date": "2019-02-20"
 }]
```

So for above should get a pie chart with only two user: 0 and 1 with 0 having the count of #2 and 1 having the count of #1 in terms of metric. The user 2 will not be included since the both the bank accounts of two are unique or never repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve the desired result using Kibana's native pie chart visualization - however, to perform the requested aggregations, you could use something similar to the following:

```
GET bank_users/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "accounts_per_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "accounts_per_bank": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "bank_name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_banks": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "accounts": "_count"
                },
                "script": "params.accounts >= 2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns the following from your sample dataset:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 9,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "accounts_per_user" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 0,
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "accounts_per_bank" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "abc bank",
                "doc_count" : 2
              },
              {
                "key" : "xyz bank",
                "doc_count" : 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "accounts_per_bank" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "xyz bank",
                "doc_count" : 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "accounts_per_bank" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note this is using default `terms` aggregations so be aware of the limitations (i.e. the fact not all documents may be retrieved, leading to inaccurate counts on large datasets with high cardinality and low `size` parameter - ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

You may be able to leverage this to create a Vega visualization.